# Trying to insert data to Excel file using OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, insert, oledb

I want a button in C# form to be able to insert data to Excel table.

This is what I did:

```
try
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            string sql = null;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\\Users\\Miko\\Documents\\WeightWatchers - Copy\\TrackingLoss.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
            sql = "Insert into [Sheet1] (Date,Loss) values(y,x)";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

When I'm trying it, [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/153707) window is open.

Anybody knows why and what to do?

Answer (score 3):

> `Extended Properties=Excel 8.0`

That means Excel 97 (`.xls`) files, not `.xlsx`.

You need to use `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml`